# Need the Slope and Intercept from Linear Regression using Tableau and R

Tags: r, linear-regression, tableau-api

I have a Dataset in Tableau, from which i need to get the Slope and Intercept of the Linear Regression best fit line using the lm() function in R.

The regression is a basic one, with just one predictor variable and one dependent. How do I handle the fact that i need to pass an aggregated value to the lm() function, even though i need to send the entire column?

With a column called 'Predictor', and another called 'Dependent', I essentially need to do this in Tableau:

```
fit <- lm(df$Dependent ~ df$Predictor)
return fit
```

Tableau does not let me do this unless I pass to it

```
SUM[Dependent] and SUM[Predictor]
```

But instead of aggregating it, i need it to work on the entire column

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a dimension to any shelf, say the detail shelf, that partitions the data at the level you wish. If you want each individual row to be included in the model, use a dimension that has a unique value for each row, say some sort of row id.

BTW, you know you can perform regression models directly within Tableau, right? You don't need to call out to R just to fit a linear model.

Comment: About the regression models within Tableau, do you mean adding a trend line? Is it possible to get the Slope and the Intercept as calculated fields from within Tableau? @Alex Blakemore

Comment: You can right click on a trend line and view the model to see the coefficients and quality metrics, but you can't access them through a calculated field, wish you could. There is an idea on the vendor site you can up vote to request that. On MS windows, you can export worksheet data, and the residuals and predicted values will be put in a table that you then view in tableau or other tools. On macs, you can export worksheet data, but it doesn't output residuals and predicted values.